# Why doesn't "/bin/sh ls" execute ls?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm new to shell, sorry if my question is too basic.I'm using Bash shell, and below is the different ways of triggering commands I have tried:

```
ls               // of course it works :)

/bin/sh ls       // error,  ")" unexpected

/bin/sh -c ls    // work just like `ls`
```

so why `/bin/sh ls` doesn't work? isn't that when I use `ls`, `ls` is an executable object in `/bin/` directory, so `ls` should be the same as `/bin/sh ls`, shouldn't it?

Comment: If given a single positional argument, that file is taken as a shell script. `ls` is a binary, and can't be used as a shell script.

Comment: What is the value of "ls" variables (type `echo $ls`)? This may explain the behavior that you observe.

Comment: `/bin/sh ls ` assumes, that you have in your working directory a file named `ls`, and this file is interpreted as a shell script for `sh`-shell. Of course this is something different from the other cases. One more difference: Only the first of the three commands invoke the bash builtin command `ls`.

Comment: @dash-o : From the other two commands, we can assume that the OP was not really typing the command `$ls`, but just `ls`; otherwise `$/bin/sh -c ls` would not have worked. I have edited the posting to remove the confusing `$`.

Comment: You most likely meant `/bin/ls`

Comment: The misunderstanding here is probably identical to the one whereby people think `sh scriptname` is the correct way to execute shell scripts, even if they're written for bash or another shell other than `sh`. As such, it's valuable to have an answer to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why /bin/sh ls doesn't work?

Some relevant parts from [posix manual sh](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html):

> sh [-abCefhimnuvx] [-o option]... [+abCefhimnuvx] [+o option]...
> [command_file [argument...]]
>
> sh -c [-abCefhimnuvx] [-o option]... [+abCefhimnuvx] [+o option]...
> command_string [command_name [argument...]]
>
> sh -s [-abCefhimnuvx] [-o option]... [+abCefhimnuvx] [+o option]...
> [argument...]

> The sh utility is a command language interpreter that shall execute commands read from a command line string, the standard input, or a specified file. The application shall ensure that the commands to be executed are expressed in the language described in Shell Command Language.

> -c
> Read commands from the command_string operand. [...]
>
> -s
> Read commands from the standard input.
>
> If there are no operands and the -c option is not specified, the -s option shall be assumed.

> *command_file*
> The pathname of a file containing commands. [....]

The:

```
 /bin/sh ls
```

case falls into `sh command_file` case. Then command file should contain shell commands to be interpreted by the shell. But `ls` is an executable most probably in ELF executable  format - nowhere near a newline separated shell commands - so shell exits with a parser error.

> isn't that when I use ls, ls is an executable object in /bin/ directory, so ls should be the same as /bin/sh ls, shouldn't it?

No.

> inconsistency when calling commands in different ways in shell?

No. Usually interpreters and compilers are written in a way that you pass files to them. When you pass a file to an interpreter or compiler, like when you do `gcc file.c` you expect the `file.c` to be written in C programming language and it will get compiled into a executable. When you write `python file` - then `file` is expected to be written in python programming language. The same way when you write `sh file` the file, whatever it is, is (on a modern/POSIX operating system) expected to be written in the POSIX sh shell language containing POSIX-compliant shell commands, not to be a shell command itself.

Answer (score 2):

`/bin/sh ls` causes `sh` to open `ls` and read it line by line for shell commands to execute.

`/bin/sh -c ls` causes `sh` to execute the command line `ls`.

In some sense, you can think of `/bin/sh ls` as equivalent to

```
/bin/sh -c 'while IFS= read -r line; do eval "$line"; done < ls'
```

Answer (score 0):

`/bin/sh` expects to get an script file as argument (when no more option is given), i.e a **text** file containing Shell command. `ls` is a **binary** file which can not be read interpreted by Shell.

Answer (score 0):

When you run ls command, it executes and show results from your current shell.

/bin/sh is a program. When you run /bin/sh -c ls, it starts a new shell instance first and in that new shell it executes ls command.

There are some particular scenarios where starting a new shell instance is preferable.